# Error while connecting Hive server 2 using beeline

Tags: hadoop, hive, hadoop2

while trying to access hiveserver2 using getting the below error.

**Error: Required field 'sessionHandle' is unset!** Struct:TGetInfoReq(sessionHandle:null, infoType:CLI_DBMS_NAME) (state=08S01,code=0) 
Driver: Hive JDBC (version 0.13.1-cdh5.3.2) 
Transaction isolation: TRANSACTION_REPEATABLE_READ 0:

jdbc:hive2://hostname> show tables;

**Error: org.apache.thrift.protocol.TProtocolException: Required field 'sessionHandle' is unset! Struct:TExecuteStatementReq(sessionHandle:null, statement:show tables, confOverlay:{}, runAsync:true) (state=08S01,code=0)**